# Sort by date when using foreach

Tags: php, sorting

I am creating a page to list select columns from each row in a table.  I have the basics of that down by using a foreach loop as below and it works fine.  The problem I am up against now is that I need to order the results by date (one of the columns) with the newest record being at the top.

This is what I have so far (that works but without sorting)

```
foreach ($visitors as $visitor) {
        $id = htmlentities($visitor['family_id']);
        $first_name = htmlentities($visitor['first_name']);
        $last_name = htmlentities($visitor['last_name']);
        $visit_date = htmlentities($visitor['visit_date']);
        $phone = htmlentities($visitor['phone']);
        $email = htmlentities($visitor['email']);
        ?>

        <p><?php echo $visit_date; ?><a href="visitor-view.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"> <?php echo $first_name . ' ' . $last_name; ?></a> <?php echo $phone; echo $email; ?></p>
        <?php
    }
```

Hoping someone has a bright idea as to how to get it to sort.

Comment: Why dont you order it in the query?

Comment: What does this have to do with sql?

Comment: why dont you get it in ordered way from query and then display it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid oversight from myself, trying to make it more complicated that it should have been.

Using suggestion from Dragon Warrior was by far the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use USORT

( Got it from PHP's official website - http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php )

```
function date_compare($a, $b)
{
    $t1 = strtotime($a['visit_date']);
    $t2 = strtotime($b['visit_date']);
    return $t1 - $t2;
}    
usort($array, 'date_compare');
```

Comment: Note, he may want `uasort` if the $visitors array has keys.